# Ammonia in an electric field - Hamiltonian in different bases

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, two-level-system

The ammonia molecule in an electric field seems to be a popular two-state system used in introductions.
The hamiltonian (in the state basis?) is usually written as:

$$\begin{pmatrix} E_1 - \mu \epsilon & -A \\\ -A & E_1 + \mu \epsilon \end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues for the energies are then $ E_1 + \sqrt{A^2 + \mu^2 \epsilon^2} $ and
$ E_1 - \sqrt{A^2 + \mu^2 \epsilon^2} $. I don't know whether a superposition of energies is possible in this system - the electric field seems to be constantly "measuring" the energy. But if it were possible, the hamiltonian for it seems to look like this:

$$\begin{pmatrix} E_1 & \sqrt{A^2 + \mu^2 \epsilon^2} \\\ \sqrt{A^2 + \mu^2 \epsilon^2} & E_1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Does this make sense? Do those two hamiltonians describe the same system? The second operator is not diagonal, so it can't be in the energy basis? What basis is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my second hamiltonian is wrong and that if one calculates correct, the superposition of stationary states yields the original hamiltonian again. I did my calculations for a slightly changed original hamiltonian but that should not matter:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} E_0 + \mu \epsilon & -A \\\ -A & E_0 - \mu \epsilon \end{pmatrix} $$
$$ E_1 = E_0 + \sqrt{A^2 + \mu^2 \epsilon^2} $$
$$ E_2 = E_0 - \sqrt{A^2 + \mu^2 \epsilon^2} $$

A superposition of $ E_1 $ and $ E_2 $ with equal amplitude has to look like this:

$$ \psi(\uparrow,t) = a_1 \cdot e^{-i \cdot E_1 \cdot t / \hbar} + a_2 \cdot e^{-i \cdot E_2 \cdot t / \hbar} $$
$$ \psi(\downarrow,t) = a_2 \cdot e^{-i \cdot E_1 \cdot t / \hbar} - a_1 \cdot e^{-i \cdot E_2 \cdot t / \hbar} $$

Notice the switched positions of $ a_1 $ and $ a_2 $ - which are the probability amplitudes of up and down in the stationary states. $ a_1 \neq a_2 $ because of the electric field. If the electric field would not be present, $ \mu \epsilon $ would be zero and $ a_1 $ would equal $ a_2 $ such that we could easily recover our hamiltonian by taking the derivative with respect to time and rearranging.

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \psi(\uparrow,t) = H_{11} \cdot \psi(\uparrow,t) + H_{12} \cdot \psi(\downarrow,t) $$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \psi(\downarrow,t) = H_{21} \cdot \psi(\uparrow,t) + H_{22} \cdot \psi(\downarrow,t) $$

In this case, it is not so straightforward but it turns out that

$$ -A \cdot \frac{a_1}{a_2} - \mu \epsilon = -A \cdot \frac{a_2}{a_1} + \mu \epsilon = \sqrt{A^2 + \mu^2 \epsilon^2} $$

Take the derivative with respect to time of $ \psi(\uparrow,t) $ and $ \psi(\downarrow,t) $. Plug in the first term for $ \sqrt{A^2 + \mu^2 \epsilon^2} $ where the exponential is multiplied with $ a_2 $ and the second where the exponential is multiplied with $ a_1 $ (leave the exponents unchanged). After some rearranging, the original hamiltonian should resurface as per the differential equation above.